# Installing boost asio on CentOS 5

Tags: c++, linux, asio

I tried running:

```
yum install boost boost-devel boost-doc


(1/3): boost-1.33.1-15.el5.i386.rpm
(2/3): boost-doc-1.33.1-15.el5.i386.rpm
(3/3): boost-devel-1.33.1-15.el5.i386.rpm
```

Then it successfully installed the boost lib, but when I compile my script:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
```

But when it gets to:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
```

Errors out:

```
Boost/asio.hpp: No such file or directory.
```

Question:
How do you install ASIO on CentOS?

---

*UPDATE*

I tried:

```
yum install asio-devel
```

Returned:

```
No package asio-devel available.
```

---

*UPDATE2*

Checked:

```
/usr/include/boost
```

And confirmed that `asio` wasn't there.
I'm trying to download the asio files and just upload it to the directory right now.
Hopefully it works.

Comment: what files does the boost-devel rpm provide? it should include Asio, are you sure they aren't in /usr/include?

Comment: Asio was in Boost since version 1.35 (IIRC). Perhaps, you've got a earlier version?

Comment: Is it possible to uninstall then try to reinstall it back to check?

Comment: I tried reinstalling and just checked and ASIO is really missing from /usr/include/boost

Comment: @IgorR. It appears that he is using CentOS 5, which includes Boost 1.33.1 which, as you suggest, would not include asio. He could use the boost 1.41.0 version which is available from epel as the package `boost141-devel`.

Comment: @sharth hello, should I `yum install boost141 boost141-devel boost141-doc` ??